# Cannot resolve if-else loop in Rails console (Rails Tutorial - Ch 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm following Micheal Hartl's Rails Tutorial and this question is from Chapter 4.

I am trying to execute following loop:

```
>> s = "foobar"
>> if s.nil?
>>   "The variable is nil"
>> elsif s.empty?
>>   "The string is empty"
>> elsif s.include?("foo")
>>   "The string includes 'foo'"
>> end
```

According to book it should print:

```
=> "The string includes 'foo'"
```

But I am getting answer : `nil`

Now I have also tried the branches one by one (i.e. just if conditions) then it works fine.

Tried several things as answered below but having same issue.

```
> if s.nil?
>   return_value = "The variable is nil"
> elsif s.empty?
>   return_value = "The string is empty?"
> elseif s.include?("foo")
>   return_value = "The string has 'foo'"
> end
=> nil
```

All this time I was using **"elseif"** instead of **"elsif"**

Comment: Thats actually should work, just add `puts`

Comment: @7urkm3n Here `puts` doesn't make any difference. I am having same issue.

Comment: This is working in my console just make sure you add 'puts' as 7urkm3n said...You should see the line printed when you run this however it will STILL return nil since the puts method always returns nil.

Comment: Yea I am doing the same thing as told by @7urkm3n

Comment: @Nirupa what version of ruby do u use ?

Comment: The version I'm using is: ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: Great contender to add  a reason for close vote: "Please review your question before posting it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this case:

**elseif** is not a correct branch command. So the code you are using actually intepreted as:

```
if s.nil?
  return_value = "The variable is nil"
elsif s.empty?
  return_value = "The string is empty?"
elseif s.include?("foo")
  return_value = "The string has 'foo'"
end
```

**Why it returns nil?** Because the code actually falls into the `else` block as you see: `not nil and not empty`

**Why elseif does not return error?** Since Ruby uses *lazy evaluation*. The `s.empty?` return false, so it does not even try to execute the block in `elsif`. Then it cannot know if elseif function is predefined or not.

Is this understandable?

So the solution is very simple, correct *elseif* to *elsif*. Have fun!

Comment: Yes That is exactly what I was doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** (disregard the comments discussion below):

An if-else loop (or any loop for that matter) will return nil in the console. All the loop does is set variables for you but not actually return them.
So to return them we will need to wrap the loop in a method like so:

```
[8] pry(main)> def my_loop
[8] pry(main)*   return_value = nil
[8] pry(main)*   s = "foobar"
[8] pry(main)*   if s.nil?
[8] pry(main)*     return_value = "The variable is nil"
[8] pry(main)*   elsif s.empty?  
[8] pry(main)*     return_value = "The string is empty?"
[8] pry(main)*   elsif s.include?("foo")  
[8] pry(main)*     return_value = "The string includes 'foo'"
[8] pry(main)*   end  
[8] pry(main)*   return_value
[8] pry(main)* end  
=> :my_loop
[9] pry(main)> my_loop
=> "The string includes 'foo'"
[10] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Then how come it doesn't work in my console? I also tried different strings, all returns nil

Comment: Yes as seen in my console, the return is "=> nil", but the line "puts return_value" outputs the correct one. Did you try it? You can post your sample console like I did if you want.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But as you said it should print the correct line first. But it doesn't.

Comment: It will return nil because you are actually not returning anything with the if-elsif loop. All your if-else loop does is set the value of **return_value** variable. This is correct. If you want to use it (the output of your loop), you can type **return_value** in your console after defining the if-else loop. You will see that return_value is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110195/discussion-between-nirupa-and-jeffrey-m-castro).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually returning anything in any of the conditions. You need to have a `puts` statement, and that will print the string.

Your way:

```
[3] pry(main)> if s.nil?
[3] pry(main)*   "blah"
[3] pry(main)* elsif s.empty?
[3] pry(main)*   "tree"
[3] pry(main)* elsif s.include?("tree")
[3] pry(main)*   "ha"
[3] pry(main)* end
=> nil
```

My way:

```
[1] pry(main)> s = "foobar"
=> "foobar"
[2] pry(main)> if s.nil?
[2] pry(main)*   puts "blah"
[2] pry(main)* elsif s.empty?
[2] pry(main)*   puts "blah"
[2] pry(main)* elsif s.include?("foo")
[2] pry(main)*   puts "tree"
[2] pry(main)* end
tree
=> nil
```

Comment: still my answer is nil..I think puts is an alternate method to print because if-else loop prints right answer even with the above code in question.